# Combination unicode string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a string like this `const str = '\u33d_rotation'`. Where `\u33` is the code for 3. This is just a simple test case. however this gives me:

> SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence

Is there anyway to combo unicode with plain?

I tried to convert it all to unicode like this:

```
'\\u' + '3d_rotation'.split('').map(char => String.charCodeAt(char).toString(16)).join('\\u')
```

So I now have:

```
const str = '\u33\u64\u5f\u72\u6f\u74\u61\u74\u69\u6f\u6e'
```

but this also gives same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicode escape sequences consist of 4 hexadecimal digits.

eg: `©` is `\u00A9`, not `\uA9`

Here are the various way to escape characters via their code point (source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals)) - note that the first two use `Latin-1` encoding and are therefore unsuitable with your code:

```
\XXX
    The character with the Latin-1 encoding specified by up to three
    octal digits XXX between 0 and 377.
    For example, \251 is the octal sequence for the copyright symbol.

\xXX
    The character with the Latin-1 encoding specified by the two
    hexadecimal digits XX between 00 and FF.
    For example, \xA9 is the hexadecimal sequence for the copyright symbol.

\uXXXX
    The Unicode character specified by the four hexadecimal digits XXXX.
    For example, \u00A9 is the Unicode sequence for the copyright symbol.

\u{XXXXX}
    Unicode code point escapes.
    For example, \u{2F804} is the same as the simple Unicode escapes \uD87E\uDC04.
```

Comment: or you could use `\xA9`

Comment: @tech4him nope, that would be latin-1 (well, ok, the latin-1 and unicode of © happen to be the same) see edited answer above

Comment: Aren't all the characters in Latin-1 the same in Unicode?

Comment: Of course, the OP probably doesn't want to use `\x`, since it would restrict you to only Latin chars, but I believe it would work if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @tech4him the point is `String.charCodeAt()` (what the OP was using) can return codepoints that don't fit in 1 byte - eg: "√".charCodeAt(0).toString(16) gives "321a" - `\x` is otherwise perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them, but use the correct Unicode escape sequences.

Like this:

```js
const str = '\u0033d_rotation';
console.log(str);
```

Or like this:

```js
const str = '\x33d_rotation';
console.log(str);
```

Or it can be easier to read like this:

```js
const str = '\u{33}d_rotation';
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Racil! This really helps! I accepted Georgiga as he has low points.